# Big theta and big 0 bounds for iteration method and Master Theorem

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, master-theorem

In Algorithms 1, I'm noticing that big-Theta running times are always used for recurrence relations when using the iteration method. Meanwhile, using the Master Theorem always seems to result in a big-O. Is this always the case for Master Theorem and iteration method, respectively?

Comment: The master theorem gives big Theta bounds, see the [Wikipedia version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Comment: Sure, linked wikipedia article states for divide-and-conquer problems where the algorithm splits into two equal sizes, then MT provides tight bounds. However, throughout the article, big O is also used interchangeably. For example, in the last table ("Application to common algorithms"), all of the bounds are expressed in big O with no reference to big Theta

Comment: It's for historical reasons. Big Theta was introduced much later, and it has become common to list running times using Big O.